# Is there an easy way to make nested array flat?

Tags: javascript, arrays

That is to make this:

`[ ['dog','cat', ['chicken', 'bear'] ],['mouse','horse'] ]`

into:

`['dog','cat','chicken','bear','mouse','horse']`

Comment: You *could* simply replace all `[` and `]` with an empty string and then add a leading and ending bracket.

Comment: So what is that thing properly called, an object , an array ?

Comment: an array. Look at http://tech.karbassi.com/2009/12/17/pure-javascript-flatten-array/

Comment: @Mike the code on that page is ghastly and relies on parsing the output of Array.prototype.toString().  My code below _does_ work.

Comment: Use the flat method arr.flat(Infinity);

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
var flattened = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
// flattened is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It's note worthy that reduce isn't supported in IE 8 and lower.

[developer.mozilla.org reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce)

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wanted. It produces ["dog","cat",["chicken","bear"],"mouse","horse"] leaving the inner array as an array instead of flattening its elements as well.

Comment: True True,  I just figured the concept is what he needed, and it looks like he got it from there.

Answer (score 24):

In modern browsers you can do this without any external libraries in a few lines:

```
Array.prototype.flatten = function() {
  return this.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    var more = [].concat(cur).some(Array.isArray);
    return prev.concat(more ? cur.flatten() : cur);
  },[]);
};

console.log([['dog','cat',['chicken', 'bear']],['mouse','horse']].flatten());
//^ ["dog", "cat", "chicken", "bear", "mouse", "horse"]
```

Answer (score 10):

Grab [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) and use the [flatten](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#flatten) function.

```
_.flatten([ ['dog','cat', ['chicken', 'bear'] ],['mouse','horse'] ]);
```

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. No need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: some people don't want to load a new script just for one functionality!

Answer (score 7):

What about this one liner code ?

```js
console.log([['dog', 'cat', ['chicken', 'bear']], [['mouse', 'horse'], 'lion']].join().split(','));
```

basically join will make  comma separated string from nested array and using split you can get 1d array, nice ? *bonus* it'll work on all major browsers as well :)

Answer (score 6):

Small fix for ChewOnThis_Trident solution and it works perfect:

```
Array.prototype.flatten = function() {
    return this.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming an array that's already unpacked from JSON, try this:

```
Array.prototype.flatten = function() {
    var r = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        var v = this[i];
        if (v instanceof Array) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(this, v.flatten());
        } else {
            r.push(v);
        }
    }
    return r;
};
```

It appears to work correctly on your input - see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Ws7L5/

Comment: That isn't necessarily true, look at http://jsfiddle.net/theycallmeswift/qfpGK/1/

Comment: yup, alert is flattening.  console.log() shows correct result.

Comment: p.s. downvote is harsh for code that actually worked but didn't show the result correctly due to unexpected alert() behaviour

Answer (score 3):

***Now in 2019*** you can easily use [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) with whatever depth you want.

```js
let arr  = [ ['dog','cat', ['chicken', 'bear'] ],['mouse','horse'] ]

let op = arr.flat(Infinity)

console.log(op)
```

Now if you want to get unique values you can combine both Set and flat

```js
let arr  = [ ['dog','cat', ['chicken', 'bear', 'cat'] ],['mouse','horse', 'dog'], [[[['deeper','chicken']]]] ]

let unique  = [...new Set(arr.flat(Infinity))]

console.log(unique)
```

[Browser comparability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) Except IE all other seems to support for IE you can use polyfill.

Comment: Random question but whats the best resource to see how node maps to chrome versions?  Found this thread after trying to use array.flat() in node 10.15.3 and having it fail despite appearing to be a valid chrome js function.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but I also ran into a situation where I needed to make a multidimensional array into 1 array and I made a function as follows.

```
function nested(arr) {
    var noNest = arr.toString().split(',').filter(Boolean),
        i = 0;

    for(i;i<noNest.length; i++){
        if(isNaN(noNest[i])){
            return console.log(noNest);
        } else {
            noNest[i] = parseInt(noNest[i]);
        }
    }
    return console.log(noNest);
}

nested([[['a']], [['b']]]);
```

This also take the nested arrays inside the tested array and makes sure its one array as the final out put

Comment: I don't need to have the Filter on it but as it currently is, this will automatically turn the numbers that are strings into integers but that is easily editable. I'm sure someone will also find this useful and not run in circles like I had to

Answer (score 1):

This solution has been working great for me, and i find it particularly easy to follow:

```
function flattenArray(arr) {
  // the new flattened array
  var newArr = [];

  // recursive function
  function flatten(arr, newArr) {
    // go through array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // if element i of the current array is a non-array value push it
      if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) === false) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
      }
      // else the element is an array, so unwrap it
      else {
        flatten(arr[i], newArr);
      }
    }
  }

  flatten(arr, newArr);

  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's why I love javascript:

```
function flattenArray(source) {
  return source.toString().split(',');
}

flattenArray([['dog', 'cat', ['chicken', 'bear']], ['mouse', 'horse']]);
// -> ['dog','cat','chicken','bear','mouse','horse']
```

Comment: It's cool when the array is small and the words don't have "," inside, once it grows, performance can be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of flattening the Objects of any depth would be using the flat method

```
var arr = [['dog','cat', ['chicken', 'bear']],[['mouse','horse'],'lion'] ]; 
var flattened = arr.flat(Infinity);
//output--> ["dog", "cat", "chicken", "bear", "mouse", "horse", "lion"]
```

[More aout Flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0):

ES6 way of doing this would be

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']].reduce((x,v) => [...x, ...v], [])
```